# Install for [ 'create-svelte@next' ] failed with code 1

Tags: node.js, svelte, svelte-component, sveltekit

I am a newbie to svelte and trying to learn about it but I couldn't set up the project from the beginning.

When I type `npm init svelte@next my-app` to start the up it throw an error in the terminal,

```
C:\Users\Ermais Kidane\Documents\REACT>npm init svelte@next my-sveltekit-pokedex               
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v14.15.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL : info using node@v14.15.0
npm ERR! Could not install from "Kidane\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\25760" as it does not contain a package.json file.
[..................] \ : info using node@v14.15.0
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ermais Kidane\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-30T12_26_34_849Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-svelte@next' ] failed with code 1
```

I update my nodeJs v16 but nothing change could you help me to solve this issue please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update npm independently:

```
npm install -g npm@next
```